# Frequency for tbats function in R

Tags: r, time-series, seasonality, frequency, tbats

I have 3 complete years + 4 weeks of weekly time series data. One of the years is a leap year. Should I calculate its frequency by $(365\times 2+366)/(3\times 7)$?

Answer (score 3):

That would work. Or just use 365.25/7, the average number of weeks in each year. The difference between leap and non-leap years is so small it shouldn't matter much.